# acts_as_tree does not destroy the model's children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-tree

I have this Task model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree :order => 'sort_order'
end
```

And I have this test

```
class TaskTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @root = create_root
  end

  def test_destroying_a_task_should_destroy_all_of_its_descendants
    d1 = create_task(:parent_id => @root.id, :sort_order => 2)
    d2 = create_task(:parent_id => d1.id, :sort_order => 3)
    d3 = create_task(:parent_id => d2.id, :sort_order => 4)
    d4 = create_task(:parent_id => d1.id, :sort_order => 5)
    assert_equal 5, Task.count

    d1.destroy

    assert_equal @root, Task.find(:first)
    assert_equal 1, Task.count
  end
end
```

The test is successful: when I destroy d1, it destroys all the descendants of d1. Thus,  after the destroy only the root is left.

However, this test is now failing after I have added a before_save callback to the Task. This is the code I added to Task:

```
before_save :update_descendants_if_necessary

def update_descendants_if_necessary
  handle_parent_id_change if self.parent_id_changed?
  return true
end

def handle_parent_id_change
  self.children.each do |sub_task|
    #the code within the loop is deliberately commented out
  end
end
```

When I added this code, `assert_equal 1, Task.count` fails, with `Task.count == 4`. I think `self.children` under `handled_parent_id_change` is the culprit, because when I comment out the `self.children.each do |sub_task|` block, the test passes again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the bug. The line

```
d1 = create_task(:parent_id => @root.id, :sort_order => 2)
```

creates d1. This calls the `before_save` callback, which in turn calls `self.children`. As Orion pointed out, this caches the children of d1.

However, at this point, d1 doesn't have any children yet. So d1's cache of children is empty.

Thus, when I try to destroy d1, the program tries to destroy d1's children. It encounters the cache, finds that it is empty, and a result doesn't destroy d2, d3, and d4.

I solved this by changing the task creations like this:

```
@root.children << (d1 = new_task(:sort_order => 2))
@root.save!
```

This worked so I'm ok with it :) I think it is also possible to fix this by either reloading d1 (`d1.reload`) or self.children (`self.children(true)`) although I didn't try any of these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`children` [is a simple has_many association](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree/tree/master/lib/active_record/acts/tree.rb#L47)

This means, when you call `.children`, it will load them from the database (if not already present). It will then cache them.

I was going to say that your second 'test' will actually be looking at the cached values not the real database, but that shouldn't happen as you are just using `Task.count` rather than `d1.children.count`. Hrm

Have you looked at the logs? They will show you the SQL which is being executed. You may see a mysql error in there which will tell you what's going on